# Error: stat_count() in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

In many of my programs I have been using ggplot2 to render charts.  I have loaded them on shinyapps.io and they are working absolutely fine.  However, when I try to run the program on my machine, i am getting the following error:

```
Error : stat_count() must not be used with a y aesthetic.
```

The following is the example code:

```
ggplot(hashtg, aes(x=reorder(hashtag, Freq), y = Freq, fill = hashtag)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") +
                geom_bar(width = 0.4) + xlab("Hashtags Used") + ylab("Number of responses") + 
                geom_text(aes(label=Freq), hjust = 1, colour = "white" )
```

The actual code has many arguments of bar graph such as title, theme & annotation, but I guess they would not hamper the output.  I am using aggregated data where `Freq` in the code is the frequency of a particular term.  When I searched for help, I repeated get instructions to use `stat = "identity"` for a bar plot.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

The session info is as follows:

```
R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.10.3 (Yosemite)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] wordcloud_2.5        RColorBrewer_1.1-2   SnowballC_0.5.1      ggplot2_2.0.0        plyr_1.8.3          
 [6] chron_2.3-47         RCurl_1.95-4.7       bitops_1.0-6         ROAuth_0.9.6         RJSONIO_1.3-0       
[11] twitteR_1.1.9        base64enc_0.1-3      tm_0.6-2             NLP_0.1-8            stringr_1.0.0       
[16] shinydashboard_0.5.1 shinyIncubator_0.2.2 shiny_0.12.2        

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.1       tools_3.2.0       digest_0.6.8      bit_1.1-12        jsonlite_0.9.17   gtable_0.1.2     
 [7] DBI_0.3.1         rstudioapi_0.3.1  curl_0.9.3        parallel_3.2.0    httr_1.0.0        bit64_0.9-5      
[13] grid_3.2.0        R6_2.1.1          magrittr_1.5      scales_0.3.0      htmltools_0.2.6   colorspace_1.2-6 
[19] mime_0.4          xtable_1.7-4      httpuv_1.3.3      labeling_0.3      stringi_0.5-5     munsell_0.4.2    
[25] slam_0.1-32       rjson_0.2.15      rstudio_0.98.1103
```

To reiterate, the same code works without a trouble in shinyapps.io.

Comment: have you compare your sessionInfo() with the server?

Comment: Not yet, don't know how to do it. I recently updated Java, and installed JRE and Android Studio...Will it be conflicting???

Comment: There have been a number of breaking changes with ggplot2's update to version 2.0.0. Compare the versions and study the NEWS from the update.

Comment: @Roland @MLavoie Many thanks...I did check.  I figured that the arguments of geom_bar() should be given together.  When I changed  the code to `geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.4)` and deleted the width argument, everything fell in place.  My current code looks like this `ggplot(hashtg, aes(x=reorder(hashtag, Freq), y = Freq, fill = hashtag)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", width = 0.4) + xlab("Hashtags Used") + ylab("Number of responses") + 
                geom_text(aes(label=Freq), hjust = 1, colour = "white" )`

Answer (score 86):

I found this link (http://tutorials.iq.harvard.edu/R/Rgraphics/Rgraphics.html)
with the solution for this error.

The column you are trying to summarize with `geom_bar()` is already summarized. You need to change `stat=stat_count` (default in `geom_bar()`) to identity.

```
+ geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Or, you can use `geom_col` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your message....in fact the problem is in defining the width argument separately, which gets resolved when you include it with stat = "identity"...as in  `geom_bar(stat='identity", width = 0.4)` essentially meaning all the arguments related to geom_bar should be declared together which is a change from the earlier version to new version of ggplot2.