# ggplot2-R Error: stat_count() must not be used with a y aesthetic

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have already checked the question below:
[Error: stat_count() in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34963138/error-stat-count-in-ggplot2)
Unfortunately, it is not helpful for me.

I have a data frame with 4 columns:
cutoff, Magnitude (factors)
TP, SD_TP (variables)

```
    "CutOff" "Magnitude" "TP" "SD_TP" 
"1" "60" "1.High Magnitude" "10.915" "0.982211657301897" 
"2" "120" "1.High Magnitude" "10.094" "1.19439967790961" 
"3" "180" "1.High Magnitude" "11.152" "0.868129972786132" 
"4" "210" "1.High Magnitude" "11.35" "0.927556122485513"
```

(this is just a part of the data frame)

I am using this code:

```
dodge <- position_dodge(width=0.9)       
 gg <- ggplot(barTP, aes(x=CutOff, y=TP, fill=Magnitude)) +
      theme(plot.title = element_text(size=30))+
      geom_bar(aes(colour = Magnitude))+
      scale_fill_manual(values=c("green", "yellow", "orange","red"))+
      labs(title = TITOLO,size=20)+
      scale_y_continuous(name = "total TPs",breaks = c(0,2,4,6,8,10,12,13), limits = c(-0.5, 14))+
      geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat="identity") +
      geom_bar(position=dodge) + geom_errorbar(limits, position=dodge, width=0.25)+
      theme(legend.text=element_text(size=15))+
      theme(legend.title=element_text(size=15))+
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour="gray0",size=15,angle=0,hjust=.5,vjust=.5,face="plain"),
            axis.text.y = element_text(colour="gray0",size=15,angle=0,hjust=1,vjust=0,face="plain"),  
            axis.title.x = element_text(colour="gray0",size=15,angle=0,hjust=.5,vjust=0,face="plain"),
            axis.title.y = element_text(colour="gray0",size=15,angle=90,hjust=.5,vjust=.5,face="plain"))
```

when I plot gg `plot(gg)` R gives this error alarm

```
Error: stat_count() must not be used with a y aesthetic.
```

the strange thing is that two days ago it worked! Now, also with the same data frame, it does not work.

I have changed nothing in the code. I have just shared the code with another PC by dropbox. But I do not think it would be the reason.

After the suggestions of @aosmith, I put `stat = "identity"`in each `geom_bar`.
It worked only after I uploaded R to the version 3.2.5 ("Very, Very Secure Dishes") and installed again `ggplot2`.

```
 gg <- ggplot(barTP, aes(x=CutOff, y=TP, fill=Magnitude)) +
   theme(plot.title = element_text(size=30))+
   geom_bar(aes(colour = Magnitude),stat="identity")+
   scale_fill_manual(values=c("green", "yellow", "orange","red"))+
   labs(title = TITOLO,size=20)+
   scale_y_continuous(name = "total TPs",breaks = c(0,2,4,6,8,10,12), limits = c(-0.5, 14))+
   geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat="identity") +
   geom_bar(position=dodge, stat="identity") + 
   geom_errorbar(limits, position=dodge, width=0.25,stat="identity")+
   theme(legend.text=element_text(size=15))+
   theme(legend.title=element_text(size=15))+
   theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour="gray0",size=15,angle=0,hjust=.5,vjust=.5,face="plain"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(colour="gray0",size=15,angle=0,hjust=1,vjust=0,face="plain"),  
        axis.title.x = element_text(colour="gray0",size=15,angle=0,hjust=.5,vjust=0,face="plain"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(colour="gray0",size=15,angle=90,hjust=.5,vjust=.5,face="plain"))

 plot(gg)
```

But now, the plot is different than in the past.[image]
In the picture, you can see a green background. In the previous ones, there were not the "big" green bars. I have understood that the green background is the barplot of the "high Magnitude" values. I am not understanding how to modify it now.

How is it possible that with new versions there so many problems? is something that I am doing wrong?

Comment: As in the question you linked to, you have multiple`geom_bar` calls but put `stat = "identity"` in only one of them.  Put `stat = "identity"` in all or collapse them together into one `geom_bar` call.

Comment: Thanks @aosmith but  no, it is still not working.
Do you suggest me to update R-studio? I have already tried to install again ggplot, but nothing new happens.

Comment: Why are you adding `geom_bar` three times (two dodged, one undodged)?  Seems like one layer, e.g., `geom_bar(aes(colour = Magnitude), stat = "identity", position = "dodge")` would give you what you want.

Comment: You ar right. I had followed some examples on the internet and I combined each part. By the way, with the previous versions it worked well.